# Frames characterised by the formula $ p \to \square_2 \diamond_1 p$

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am trying to solve exercises from the book [Modal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521527147) by  Patrick Blackburn, Maarten de Rijke and Yde Venema. I am having a problem to solve one of the exercises in the section 3.1, the exercise is 3.1.1 in page 131. Please help me.

> **Exercise** :
>   Consider a language with two diamonds $\diamond_1$ and $\diamond_2$. Show that the formula $\alpha := p \to \square_2 \diamond_1 p$ is valid on precisely those frames where the two relations $R_1 \text{ and } R_2$ satisfy $\forall xy (R_2xy \to R_1yx)$

Now I am able to show one part of the problem which is whenever in a frame $R_1 \text{ and } R_2$ satisfy $\forall xy (R_2xy \to R_1yx)$, $\alpha$ is valid there.

But I have stuck in the opposite direction. Suppose $\alpha$ is true in a frame and let $R_2xy$. I can not find a suitable approach to show $R_1yx$. I have though about breaking into cases when $M \text{ (corresponding model) },x \vDash p$ and  $M,x \vDash \lnot p$. But it is not helping me. I am completely stuck here.

Perhaps I am missing something.Please help me to solve this problem. 
I will be very grateful. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

We will prove the converse ...

Assume that there are two "worlds" $x,y$ such that :

> $R_2xy$ and $\lnot R_1yx$.

Assume that $x \vDash p$ and $y \nvDash p$; in this way, $y \nvDash \diamond_1 p$, because there are no worlds "accesible$_1$" to $y$ where $p$ is *true*.

But $p$ is *false* in a world "accesible$_2$" to $x$ (i.e. in $y$) and thus : $x \nvDash \square_2\diamond_1 p$.

In conclusion :

> $x \vDash p$ and $x \nvDash \square_2\diamond_1 p$

i.e.

> > $x \nvDash p \to \square_2\diamond_1 p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have little confusions in two places. Will you please help me?

First of all I don't understand why $y\nvDash p$ implies "there are no worlds "$\text{accesible}_1$" to y where p is true." I mean the formula says whenever $p$ is true, $\square_2 \diamond_1 p$ is true. From there how should I conclude your claim?

Secondly, only the case $x\nvDash p$ is considered here. But what will happen if $x\nvDash p$? How should I approach in that case?

May be I am missing something easy. Please help me.

Comment: Suggestion : write a graph with two point : $x,y$ and the arrows for $R_1$ and $R_2$ : the arrow $R_1$ from $y$ to $x$ must be "crossed", because $\lnot R_1yx$. Due to $y \nvDash p$ and the fact that $x \vDash p$, we have that : for **no** world "accessible$_1$" to $y$, $p$ is *true* ($p$ is *false* in $y$ and $x$ in not accessible to it). Thus, applying the clause for "possible", we have that $y⊭⋄_1 p$.

Comment: Now we have : $x \vDash p$, and thus also $x⊭⋄_1 p$ (because $x$ is "accessible$_1$" to itself), and $y⊭⋄_1 p$. But $y$ is "accessible$_2$" to $x$, and thus, applying the clause for "necessary", we have to conclude that $x⊭□_2 ⋄_1 p$.

Comment: Thnx again. And I am really sorry I am not getting the cause of non existence of any world accessible by $R_1$ to y where p is true. I am fine with the fact that p is true in x but x is not  accessible by $R_1$ to y. But there can be world z ($\neq$ x)with $R_1yz$ and p is true in z. Then what will go wrong actually? Please help.

Comment: And in your previous comment I am not getting why x should be accessible to x by $R_1$? $R_1$ is not given to be reflexive I think. Am I missing again something?

Comment: We are working by contradiction; assuming that $∀xy(R_2xy→R_1yx)$ does not hold means to imagine a frame such that $\exists xy \lnot (R_2xy→R_1yx)$ i.e. $\exists xy (R_2xy \land \lnot R_1yx)$. *It's Ok so far ?* Now we build a "minimal" model with only $x,y$ satisfying this formula : this is why we have to "break" the arrow $R_1$ from $y$ to $x$. 1/2

Comment: Now, review the answer and the comments above ... If you find that the argument it's enough to show that $x⊨p$ and $x⊭□_2 ⋄_1 p$, we have to apply the clause for $\to$ and conclude with $x⊭p \to □_2 ⋄_1 p$. Having found a frame where the formula $\alpha$ is **not** true, is enough to conclude that it is not *valid* (i.e. not true in **all** frames). 2/2

Comment: But we are not given $\lnot R_1xx$ either...

Comment: Thank you very much. Thnx a lot. I have got it now. Considering a particular frame ("minimal" as you said) is the key part of the proof. I was missing this.
Sorry for that.
Thank you again for this nice answer.

Comment: Though I was convinced with the answer but now I have  a little confusion again. I am sorry to ask you so much. Please help me.

The argument is by contradiction and thus we are assuming there is a frame say $F$ satisfies the formula $\alpha$ but the relations $R_1,R_2$ does not satisfy the given condition and hence $\exists x,y (R_2xy\land\lnot R_1yx)$

Then we build the minimal model say $F_1$ with two worlds x,y such that $R_2xy\land \lnot R_1yx$. Now my question is why this minimal model $F_1$ should also satisfy the formula $\alpha$?Then only we can arrive at a contraction.

Comment: @usermath - Sorry, my ,istake: the proof is not by contradiction. We want to prove : "**if** $\alpha$ is valid in a frame with $R_1$ and $R_2$, **then** it satisfy $∀xy(R_2xy → R_1yx)$; i've proved the *converse* : "assume that the frame does not satisfy ... and show that $\alpha$ is not valid".

Comment: No problem at all. I got an idea from your answer and managed to find a solution. I have posted it as an answer. Hope it is correct. Please have a look and rectify me if there is any mistake. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a solution from the idea of Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer. I hope it is correct. Please comment and rectify if there is any mistake. Thanks.

To show the converse part (i.e. whenever a frame $F$ satisfies $\alpha$, it satisfies the condition $\forall xy (R_2xy \to R_1yx)$) we go by contradiction.

Assume if possible there is a frame $F$ which satisfies $\alpha$ but $\exists xy$  such that $R_2xy$ and $\lnot R_1yx$

Then consider a valuation $V$ such that $V(p)=\{x\}$ and since $F$ satisfies $\alpha$ hence $\alpha$ is true at $x$ under $V$ i.e.

$F,V,x \vDash p \to \square_2 \diamond_1 p$

$\Rightarrow F,V,y \vDash  \diamond_1 p$ as $R_2xy$

$\Rightarrow \exists z : R_1yz \text{ and } F,V,z \vDash p$

But $\lnot R_1yx$ means $z \ne x$ and $F,V,z \vDash p$ means $z\in V(p)$ which is a contradiction as $V(p)=\{x\}$

Hence the proof.